# direct manipulation of long value in string in C

Tags: c, memory, io, byte, increment

I'm trying to find a low-latency solution (preferably in one or two statements) where I can directly increment a value in memory.

Let's assume this is my string data:

```
123ABCD456DEFABABCDCD.,.,?!!X
```

What I want to do is make the program read the first ABCD as the actual integer value which should be equal to:

```
 68 (D) + 67 (C) * 256 (in 3rd position) + 66 (B) * 65536 (in 2nd position) + 65 (A) * 65536* 256 (in 1st position)
 which equals a 4-byte value of: 1,094,861,636 or 41424344 hex.
```

I want to then make my string set to:

```
123ABCE456DEFABABCDCD.,.,?!!X
```

which means the 4-byte value needs to be 1,094,861,637 or 41424345 hex.

This is the code I attempted to use:

```
char* pointer=data; //data pointer has been set to valid memory space containing the data
long *offset=(long*)pointer+3;
*offset++;
```

I know this code will be somewhat successful:

```
    char* pointer=data; //data pointer has been set to valid memory space containing the data
char *offset=pointer+3;
long number=(long)*offset;
number++;
sprintf(offset,"%d",number);
```

But I want to manipulate more than one byte of memory when doing the increment.

What is the easiest way to do this without using functions that could produce high latency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small adjustment to your code:

```
char* pointer=data; //data pointer has been set to valid memory space containing the data
long *offset=(long*)pointer+3;
(*offset)++;
```

The difference is the parentheses in `(*offset)++`. Without the parentheses, you are incrementing the pointer. With the parentheses, you are incrementing the value pointed to by the pointer.

Now, this will probably only do what you expect if you are running on a big-endian architecture, and `long` is a 32-bit type. If not, then you'll have to do something slightly different.

Comment: It may also have some interesting problems regarding alignment. Most of the finicky architectures where that can surface are indeed BE, so the very platform that this is hoping to work on may be its undoing. The only reason I mention it is the simple fact this is being done **three** octets deep on a `char` sequence.

Comment: I should be ok because I'm testing on a 32-bit processor where the final result is on a 64-bit processor. I was going to consider using ints but because I want to comply with 64-bit processors,  I feel I have to use longs for better alignment.

Comment: @Mike: If you're mixing 32 bit and 64 bit architectures, then that sort of naive solution probably isn't going to work. At the very least, you will have to test it on each target architecture to ensure that it does what you want. (If you use a definite 32-bit type like `uint32_t`, then it might work.)

Comment: @Even if the test on 32 bit passes, it can very well fail on 64 bit and/or with other compiler optimizations. BE systems tend to enforce aligned load/stores for instance.

Comment: @Mike It is actually *less* likely to function properly on Intel x64 than x86. Add little-endian to that and it won't do what you want *at all*. And some platforms will outright-bus-error trying to address a `long` (32 or 64 bit, I don't care which) not lying at an address fulfilling the processor alignment requirements for that type.. Do what Greg said; test it thoroughly on *every* architecture intended to run it.

Comment: @WhozCraig Indeed, the most common architectures currently in desktop and notebook computing (x86 and x64) have modes to enable *alignment checking*. Any code which violates alignment requirements will segfault when that mode is enabled. We can see proof of this in the form of [an example on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error#Example)... I would introduce this kind of code as an optimisation *only after all significant bottlenecks (as identified by a profiler) have been looked into first*.

Comment: @Mike: Why do you ask anyway if you do not even think about the answers given, just as they do not please you? Asking is dangerous: you might not get what you wanted, but what you asked for. So, next time just do trial and error and do not ask, there are others here who really want to improve their programming skills and not just confirm what they do.

Answer (score 1):

That will not work if the architecture requires alignment.
Even if not, this depends on endianess. It only works on big endian, which are getting rarer these days. x86/64 and most ARM are actually little endian which have the bytes swapped.

So, best use the compliant way:

```
uint8_t *data;
uint32_t val = ((uint32_t)data[0] << 24) | ((uint32_t)data[1] << 16) | ...
val++;
data[3] = (uint8_t)val; val >>= 8;
data[2] = (uint8_t)val; val >>= 8;
data[1] = (uint8_t)val; val >>= 8;
data[0] = (uint8_t)val; val >>= 8;
```

Note to use uint8_t and uint32_t, but not char and long: Both are not guaranteed to have exactly 8 and 32 bits (char very likely on current CPUs, but long can have very well 64 bits. Note that we require unsigned types. `long` is signed and char can be either or.
The typecasts will not cost any code on ARM and Intel at least (not sure about other 32 bit CPUs, though). On 8 bit the following will be faster.

The code might very well be optimized by the compiler to a simple load/store, but you really should not make your code rely on this.

An alternative for 8 bitters would be:

```
if ( !++data[3] )
    if ( !++data[2] )
        if ( ...
            ;
```

This will be faster on 8 bit architectures than first loading all 32 bits. Actually you can do hardly faster on those, even in assembler (unless your compiler screws it). It also is only guaranteed to work on unsigned due to the wrap-around (undefined on signed). You could also use pre decrement, starting with `data += 4, which might save code on some architectures.

On >=32 Bit architecture however, I strongly recommend using the first variant.

Comment: What I'm going to do is make the offset from the main allocation a multiple of 4 or 8 and stick with longs and see if I get success there. I was using offset 3 in my question as an example.

Comment: @Mike: (Re)read my answer very carefully. If you are on Intel or ARM, you are very likely screwed with your approach anyway!

Comment: I did manage to do direct manipulation both on 32-bit and 64-bit processors via entire structs with varying data types. Both systems are intel. If worst case for storing a long is 64-bits then I should be ok because I reserved about 16 bytes of memory for storing a value and I don't think storing a long would exceed 8 bytes (aka 64-bits) under any architecture?

Comment: P.S. I did some reading and according to this: http://www.unix.org/whitepapers/64bit.html, a long uses up to 64-bits depending on the system. Both systems I'm using are linux.

Comment: @Mike: Why cite a whitepaper if the only relevant thing - the standard - is at hand? Read [C11 draft](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1); a long can actually have any size larger than 31 bits.